# Facebook API - how to publish/share with big photo

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I'm have followed a very [clear tutorial](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-add-facebook-share-button-to-your-web-site-pages/) to publish (share) a story on fb timeline.
You can see the code I am using on my [website](http://www.paulgodard.com/) behind the FB Share button.
How can I force the photo to be bigger instead of a thumbnail? 
What should I add to the js code (FB.ui)? An action? 
But what should I write it? 
I am very new to FB api, so please in plain english... Thank you!
Paul

Comment: You perhaps want to upload a picture with a link in the description instead of a post with a link and its thumbnail?

Answer (score 4):

I went through your code. You are using feed method.

```
FB.ui(
{
method: 'feed',
name: 'Paul Godard – Soul Photography',
link: 'http://www.paulgodard.com/',
picture: 'http://www.gondwanastudio.com/xMedia/Images/Photos/PG_010501-011000/PG_010927.jpg',
source: '',
caption: 'Paul Godard | Soul Photography | Landscape | Nature | Fine Art',
description: 'I am blessed.  I have 2 wonderful children Enya and James and my best friend is their mother, my soulmate for many years.  I live in a wonderful home in Africa, the wildest continent of the world.  I am very privileged and grateful.  There is so much beauty around us but people dont see it anymore...',
message: ''
});
```

Insted of this, try using photos method as follows

```
FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
                        message: 'your message',
                        status: 'success',
                        access_token: access_token,
                        url: 'your_Img_url'
                    }, function(response) {
                    });
```

Here we are uploading a photo. It will get saved in a new album since we have not created any in above code and a big photo will get posted on your wall.

Comment: But how can we implement sharing function like when clicking on "Share" button under a post? I find that when clicking this button, my timeline has a sharing post, but the image is not saved to my album (that I prefer)